# Ionic Shows blank Screen after splash screen on Android after build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I am creating android app useing ionic3 .whenver i create build of my project and install it on my android phone it shows blank screen after splash screen But it's working fine on web theres no error in console i have tried every think which i thought might be causing this but wasn't able to figure this on my own any help on this would be appreciated Thank you

Comment: Is there any console output when using remote debugging in chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app using the command

```
ionic cordova run android
```

it will run in the debug mode, so when the app will be launched in development mode it will take time to load all the modules that's why it takes too much of time. If you don't want that means you can use the below cmd to run your app.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

this cmd will take more time to build but the blank screen will not be shown.Hope this helps you all the best in advance.